# tips on creating a component library for angular/react components

Tags: angular, reactjs, npm, shared-libraries

I'm trying to head up a potential project at work that would require our company to use components for our projects so that our products will have universal look/functionality to our brand. The main caveat is how do I manage this in such a way that updates/changes to components in the library automatically apply to all projects using them? Any basic tips on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Make your component library a package just like everything else, and all projects using it are responsible for updating that dependency. You don't want "automatic" sharing. Trust me.

Comment: Thank you for the info, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatically is a strong word. The best way to go about creating a shared component library is to use NPM or even setup a private NPM repository at your company. Then any consumer of your library can just `npm install` like any other dependency and update whenever they want

Comment: Your right. By automatically I just meant not having to go and manually create the changes in every single component. Judging by the answers this will be as straight-forward as I had hoped. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a thought, but wouldn't it be TECHNICALLY possible to host all of the components on a shared server and import them? I've personally never tried to import from outside of my own app folder so this is honestly just a question and is probably bad practice anyways.

Comment: @Brandon Miller -I'm very interested in hearing out some responses to that. It is entirely not an option for me. As my company is very stringent about things and I don't have to ask to know that it's going in BitBucket. But I love hearing out some out of the box scenarios played out...

Comment: Use monorepo concept via lerna